# How does C# GMap.Net.Windows NuGet Package and Google Maps licensing work ? Is it legal to use both for commercial use?

Tags: licensing, microsoft, google-code

I'm developing tracking software using c# windows forms and the NuGet GMap.NET.Windows package by Jurgen De Leon Rodriguez. The problem is will it be legal to use the GMap package in my c# application with google maps for commercial use? How does the licensing work, do I have to pay for something ?

https://github.com/judero01col/GMap.NET/wiki/License, the license say you can use GMap for development but

> *WARNING: This software can access some map providers and may viotile* (sic) *their Terms of Service, you use it at your own risk, nothing is forcing you to accept this Source itself is legal!*

scares me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code appears to be legal to use as it's under some sort of permissive license. I read this disclaimer as a hint that Google Maps licensing is separate.

For Google Maps you need to comply with [ToS](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/) and may be required to pay: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/.